Yii framework issues while moving vue components
Yii framework using component in other views
<component-carousel title="<?php echo t("Popular nearby")?>" featured_name="popular" :settings="{
              theme: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote('rounded')?>',       
              items: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(5)?>', 
              lazyLoad: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(true)?>', 
              loop: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(true)?>', 
              margin: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(15)?>', 
              nav: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(false)?>', 
              dots: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(false)?>', 
              stagePadding: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(10)?>', 
              free_delivery: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote( t("Free delivery") )?>',       
          }" :responsive='<?php echo json_encode($responsive);?>' />
        </component-carousel><component-carousel title="<?php echo t("Popular nearby")?>" featured_name="popular" :settings="{
              theme: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote('rounded')?>',       
              items: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(5)?>', 
              lazyLoad: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(true)?>', 
              loop: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(true)?>', 
              margin: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(15)?>', 
              nav: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(false)?>', 
              dots: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(false)?>', 
              stagePadding: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote(10)?>', 
              free_delivery: '<?php echo CJavaScript::quote( t("Free delivery") )?>',       
          }" :responsive='<?php echo json_encode($responsive);?>' />
        </component-carousel>

Hey, need some help, I have this: components that works in the index.php page and so I wanted to use it else where.
but then I messed up my merchant.php page(404) so after some troubleshoot find out that change this in the controller solved the 404 issue but the component doesn't show up
public function actionPartener()
    {
        $setttings = Yii::app()->params['settings'];
        $this->render('merchant-partener', [
            'responsive'=>AttributesTools::FrontCarouselResponsiveSettings('full'), 
            'settings'
        ]);
        
    }


I tried all i could do, I'm still a beginner so… and sorry for my poor english
